# apche mesos - install ubuntu 18.04 - start master failed - mesos version 1.6.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, mesos

I tried to install Apache Mesos 1.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, but start master failed error

> ./bin/mesos-master.sh: line 24: /home/hdpu00/mesos-1.4.0/build/src/mesos-master: No such file or directory

below details about installation process i tried:
mesos tar file
`tar -zxf mesos-1.4.0.tar.gz`

install the required packages and other Mesos dependencies.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git<br>
$ sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk<br>
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev \ 
                          python-six python-virtualenv \
                          libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev \
                          libsasl2-modules maven libapr1-dev \
                          libsvn-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Build mesos

```
$ cd mesos-1.4.0
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

Run Mesos: from directory `/home/hdpu00/mesos-1.4.0/build/`, I run the command: `$ ./bin/mesos-master.sh –ip=127.0.0.1 –work_dir=/var/lib/mesos`

*(I had previously created the dir /var/lib/mesos , and set up permissions correctly)*

but run master mesos failed, how can i debug this error
`/home/hdpu00/mesos-1.4.0/build/src/mesos-master: No such file or directory`

thank you in advance for your help

O.S

Comment: What's in `/home/hdpu00/mesos-1.4.0/build/`? Can you list the content? Why are you trying Mesos 1.4 while there is 1.9

Comment: hi janisz, thank you for your help , i fix the issue using this command sudo ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h , there was a setup to do because mesos expect af file xlocale.h instead of locale.h . Finally i have installed mesos correctly.  OS